# Send data from device to device

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, notifications, device

I'm working on local simple chat app for my small company that sends messages from device to device.
Each device is assigned a unique number (for example, 111,112,113, ...).
I need a way to send a message from device (111) to device (112) directly.
I used Push notification, it worked fine, but Notification Settings has to be enabled for the app.
Is there an alternative way to send date from device to device directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use Bluetooth communication via GameKit.  Here's the code for a simple chat application using that approach.  The example is a few years old but is still relevant:

http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502